# Type of value collection to be passed of NSUpdatedObjectsKey or NSDeletedObjectsKey for mergeChangesFromRemoteContextSave:

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In my current application, I have CoreData implementation with multiple contexts in place for achieving concurrency. I am seeing crashes from iOS side while I pass remoteMergeChanges to different contexts with the ManagedObjectIDs in NSUpdatedObjectsKey or NSDeletedObjectsKey keys.

I am sending an NSArray of managedObjectIDs as the value to this keys for merging to other contexts.

Could anyone help me with this?

The crash I observes saying,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** **-[NSMutableSet
>   unionSet:]: set argument is not an NSSet'**
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010afb3b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
>
> 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010aa18141
>   objc_exception_throw + 48      2   CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010af3a051 -[NSMutableSet unionSet:] + 1041    3   CoreData
>   0x0000000107b3ddf8 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willReadWithContents:] +
>   936    4   CoreData                            0x0000000107aef346
>   -[_NSFaultingMutableSet count] + 22    5   CoreData                            0x0000000107b119a2 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods)
>   _propagateDelete:] + 1554      6   CoreData                            0x0000000107b111de
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _propagateDeletesUsingTable:] + 574      7   CoreData                            0x0000000107b10f2b
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processDeletedObjects:] + 1099      8   CoreData                            0x0000000107afa90d
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _propagatePendingDeletesAtEndOfEvent:] + 109     9   CoreData                            0x0000000107af5b7b
>   -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 1531

Comment: The merge dictionary is created automatically by core data you just pass it into `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`.  Since iOS 10 I haven't had a reason for do it - I just use `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES`.  What exactly are you doing? and why?

Comment: Thank you @JonRose, It seems I have to update my CoreData stack implementation to the new way of implementation. I am still using the old style of keeping main queue context and private queue contexts separately. I don't do a parent-child way of handling the managed object contexts. Do you have any suggestion for reference?

Comment: It is a little late, but the crash log says CoreData wants to handle an NSSet while you apparently pass in an Array...